# html javacsript how to change background image of section while on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

hey guys i am new to javascript and i am trying to figure out how to change the background image of my section while hovering the respective texts. currently i want to load 3 different backgrounds but i have issues trying to figure out. below is the code im using .do lmk if u have any suggestions. thanks in advance .

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>3d model</title>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Krona+One&display=swap');
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* custom webkit scrollbar
     */
    
    html {
      -ms-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    }
    
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      font-family: 'Krona One', sans-serif;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    
    canvas {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .section {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      scroll-snap-align: center;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 5vw;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: white;
      line-height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    h2 {
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 6vw;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
      color: transparent;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<section class="section">
  <h1 id="gold">Gold</h1>

  <h2 id="silver">Silver</h2>
  <h1 id="blue">Light Blue</h1>
</section>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Create a class:hover css that has the hover image url as background-image, and put the original image url in the original class

Comment: but wouldnt u only be able to set only 1 background-image?

Comment: and i mean to make it such that when i hover the text then will change background, not hover over the background

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:hover` property in CSS to add styles only whenever the mouse is over the specific HTML element; and to add an image you can use the CSS property `background: url(URL_HERE);`

For example, your `gold` ID can be set to display a background by creating a specific `:hover` property as such:

```
#gold:hover {
    background: url(" https://via.placeholder.com/600x200.png/FFFF00/");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>3d model</title>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Krona+One&display=swap');
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* custom webkit scrollbar
     */
    
    html {
      -ms-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    }
    
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      font-family: 'Krona One', sans-serif;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    
    canvas {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .section {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      scroll-snap-align: center;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 5vw;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: white;
      line-height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    h2 {
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 6vw;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
      color: transparent;
    }
    
    #gold:hover {
      background: url(" https://via.placeholder.com/600x200.png/FFFF00/");
    }
    
    #silver:hover {
      background: url(" https://via.placeholder.com/600x200.png/CCCCCC/");
    }
    
    #blue:hover {
      background: url(" https://via.placeholder.com/600x200.png/0000FF/");
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="section">
    <h1 id="gold">Gold</h1>

    <h2 id="silver">Silver</h2>
    <h1 id="blue">Light Blue</h1>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

For every image, you would need to provide a separate class - if you don't want this behaviour, consider using JavaScript instead to dynamically adjust the background image.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the element and then you need to set the backgroundImage  property to that element like

```
var goldElement = document.getElementById('gold');
goldElement.addEventListener('mouseover'), (event)=> { `goldElement.style. backgroundImage = "url('path_to_image')" ` }
```

And change the background to normal when mouse leave.

```
goldElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event)=> { `goldElement.style. backgroundImage = "url('')" ` });
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>3d model</title>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Krona+One&display=swap');
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* custom webkit scrollbar
     */
    
    html {
      -ms-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    }
    
    body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      font-family: 'Krona One', sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    
    canvas {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .section {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      scroll-snap-align: center;
      user-select: none;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 5vw;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: white;
      line-height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    h2 {
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 6vw;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
      color: transparent;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="section">
    <h1 id="gold" onMouseOver="gold()" onMouseOut="leave()">Gold</h1>
    <h2 id="silver" onMouseOver="silver()" onMouseOut="leave()">Silver</h2>
    <h1 id="blue" onMouseOver="blue()" onMouseOut="leave()">Light Blue</h1>
  </section>
  <script>
    var sect = document.querySelector('section');
    function gold(){
      sect.style.background = '#FFD700';
    }
    function silver(){
      sect.style.background = '#C0C0C0';
    }
    function blue(){
      sect.style.background = '#ADD8E6';
    }
    function leave(){
      sect.style.background = '#000000';
    }
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to stay on the color just hovered, then remove the leave function from the above code and from the Tags too.